# How to monkey patch Numeric in config/application.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching

I would like to know if it's possible to monkey patch the Numeric DSL in the `config/application.rb` file. I'm trying to with:

```
Numeric.include CoreExtensions::Numeric
```

At the end of the file. But when I try to run the local server I see:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant CoreExtensions
```

The CoreExtensions namespace exists within `app/lib/core_extensions`.

Thanks.

Comment: You can move it into initialize folder or use eager_load lib files i think.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the former?

Comment: Did you require the file in the lib folder explicitly or did you enable autoloading for that folder?

Comment: ^^ You can just `require Rails.root.join("app", "lib", "core_extensions")` from the initializer file

Comment: Numeric is not a domain specific language. Its an object that represents various types of numbers.